# Problems unstagging a bad commit

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to commit some modifications I made in my repository; but received the following answer:

I tried using  git reset HEAD Final Project/Gcode/Prueba BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt

And it didn't worked.

This is the actual git status

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Final Project/Gcode/Prueba BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    Final Project/Gcode/Prueba BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        Final Project/Gcode/Prueba_BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt
```

I need to be able to push my advances to the repository.

Comment: This is a good reason to not allow spaces in file names.

Comment: No, it's just a good reason to learn how to use your shell.

Comment: Also, "unstagging a commit" is confusing *at best*. (But people got what you asked, so I guess it's no big deal here?)

Answer (score 2):

`git reset HEAD "Final Project/Gcode/Prueba BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt"` should be enough.

You had a space char between the `!` and the extension of file, which made command prompt parse two parameters: `[filename]` and `.txt`.

Putting everything into quotes should resolve the matter.

Comment: Note the quotes around the file name because of the special characters. (This is for the OP and future visitors, not you as the answerer.)

Comment: This is what I received after using tha command:
`
$ git reset HEAD "Final Project/Gcode/Prueba BioMaterial_Funciono! .txt"
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/j_tom/Desktop/Fab_Academy/Otro_Repo/FabAcademy/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
`

Comment: The message is clear enough: close editors or applications that may be using that lock, or just delete the lock.

Comment: I deleted the file, and restarted the computer. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it the same error message ?